# validation rule to check on at field before I close a case

Tags: validation-rule

I am writing a validation rule to check on the field Close_Reason__c has data selected from the picklist. Before I close the case. below is the validation rule  Close_Reason__c is blank it still close the case.

```
AND(ISCHANGED(  Status  ),ISPICKVAL( Status , "Closed"), NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT( Close_Reason__c ) ) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should return true when there IS an error, so the NOT is erroneous. As an aside, since Close Reason is a picklist, you should use ISPICKVAL:

```
AND(
  ISCHANGED(Status),
  ISPICKVAL(Status,'Closed'),
  ISPICKVAL(Close_Reason__c,'')
)
```

Comment: thanks that did it.